# Cannot insert new row on triggered table - "statement contains an output clause without into"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, azure

I created a procedure, and I want to call it when row ll be inserted into my table. So I created trigger with After insert clause which executes my procedure.

And my question is why I have error while I am trying to insert new row into my table:

> The target table 'dbo.mytable' of the DML statement cannot have any
>   enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without
>   INTO clause.

I am working on SQL Azure, and inserting new row from Managment Portal if that's important information?

## Procedure myproc

```
BEGIN
delete from mytable where Login like 'oo';
END
```

## Trigger mytrigg

```
create TRIGGER mytrigg
ON dbo.mytable
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
   EXEC dbo.myproc;
END
GO
```

Comment: Is that the full procedure?  or do you have an output variable slated for output on the procedure?

Comment: Yes it's without any variables, parameters etc. I copy / paste it.

Comment: Try adding SET NOCOUNT ON to the stored procedure just after the BEGIN. This will prevent SQL Server returning any DONE_IN_PROC messages which are returned as a result set with number of rows affected. Give it a try.

Comment: I've tried and still same error.

Comment: According to create.msdn this is an issue with the portal/managent designer. So I'll create a procedure that will do work. It can be even better way...